# UIDocumentPickerViewController - each file that was picked once is then grayed out

Tags: ios, ios8, icloud-drive, uidocumentpickervc

I'm using `UIDocumentPickerViewController` on iOS 8 to allow users to open documents in iCloud Drive.

I use `UIDocumentPickerModeOpen` with the custom UTI of my app's document:

```
UIDocumentPickerViewController *pickerViewController = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc]
  initWithDocumentTypes:@[[MySampleDocument documentUTI]] 
  inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];

pickerViewController.delegate = self;

[self presentViewController:pickerViewController animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

This works fine at first. The documents of my app show, the user can pick a document, and it gets opened in the app.

However, if I then use the document picker *a second time, the same document that I just picked is now grayed out* and cannot be picked again.

Why is that?

The document is still grayed out even after I quit the app. I even deleted the app and installed it again. The document is still grayed out.

I'm using UIDocument so starting and stopping security scoped access is take care of.

Comment: If any1 found answer to this please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured this out. The document UTI in my Info.plist had to conform to `public.data`. Once I added this, the entries are not grayed out anymore.

Another positive side effect is that the `kMDItemContentType` of NSMetadtaQuery results now finally show the correct UTI and not `dyn.abc1234...` anymore.

Here is the updated and working type definition:

```
<key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>
<array>
    <string>public.composite-content</string>
    <string>public.data</string>      ← This part was missing before.
</array>
```